# Weather API call from Java web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, weather-api

I am calling an api: openweathermap.org. If I call the url (strUri as formed in the below code after passing the city name and API key properly) directly in the address bar, it works fine but from the application, it throws an exception as:

api.openweathermap.org; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: api.openweathermap.org.

java.net.UnknownHostException: api.openweathermap.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_51]

Please help. I am using RESTTemplate and spring-boot for the application.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String weatherPost(@ModelAttribute City city, ModelMap model) throws URISyntaxException{
    String apiKey="myApIKey";//Removed my original API Key for posting.
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    String strUri= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city.getName()+",AU&appid="+apiKey+"&units=metric";
    URI uri = new URI(strUri);
    RequestEntity<String> request = new RequestEntity<String>(HttpMethod.GET,uri);
    ResponseEntity <WeatherResponse> weatherResponse = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, WeatherResponse.class);
    City myCity = new City();
    model.put("weatherResponse", weatherResponse);
    model.put("city", myCity);
    return "weather";
}
```

Comment: post your code whatever you tried so far?

Comment: Well the error says everything: UnknownHostException. And since `api.openweathermap.org` is a valid hostname and gets resolved by dnswatch.info to `178.62.223.38` and `178.62.213.57` I do assume you have an issue with your machine.

Comment: Check your firewall settings. See if Java process is allowed to create outgoing connections

Comment: here's [one that works](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/weather-app) if that helps

Comment: I think there is some firewall issue. How can i check the outgoing connections and the firewall settings stopping it.